# why does recursive numeric method print out its output

Tags: java, recursion

Can anyone tell me in the simplest way why this prints out **321123** when ***generate(123)*** is called?  I understand why it prints out 321, but the 123 part eludes me.

```
 /** @param x an integer such that x >= 0
 */ 

public void generate(int x) {     

     System.out.print(x % 10);     

     if ((x / 10) != 0) {         
        generate(x / 10);     
     }     
     System.out.print(x % 10); 
}
```

Comment: Draw a graph with the stack calls of the method maybe it should be easier to see.

Comment: I suggest you grab a piece of paper and write out what you think each step of the code will do. Afterwards, execute your program and see if it corresponds. If it doesn't, use a debugger or println statements to find where you're wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The recursion goes "in", then comes back "out". Think of it this way:

```
generate(123) {
    System.out.print(123 % 10)          // 3

    generate(12) {
        System.out.print(12 % 10)       // 2

        generate(1) {
            System.out.print(1 % 10)    // 1
            System.out.print(1 % 10)    // 1
        }

        System.out.print(12 % 10)       // 2
    }

    System.out.print(123 % 10)          // 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I understand in theory better, but what i realize is that my real problem is that i'm not fully understanding recursion.  Time to sharpen up a bit.

Comment: Each time `generate` is called, it opens a new scope just like any other method call. The way I have pictured it is very close to what actually happens, except that the inner scopes cannot see the outer scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Because you print `x%10` both before and after your recursive call. When the number is 123, it prints 3, does the work for 12, then prints 3 again.

When it gets 12, it prints 2, does the work for 1, then prints 2 again.

Same for the 1. So you get "nested" prints of the remainder in each call.

Answer (score -1):

Entrance to deeper function levels:

if ((x / 10) != 0) {
        generate(x / 10);
     }

is also exit with the filo order which reverses 321 to 123

becasue there is another

System.out.print(x % 10);

after that.